# Understanding and managing c++ program crash handling in windows

Tags: c++, windows, crash, mingw

I have a c++ program compiled with MinGW which links to libmicrohttpd to run a webserver. It normally functions correctly, but I am trying to do some robustness testing and for my current test I have tried to disable the network interface. This results in the program crashing with the dialog box: "MyProgram.exe has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Rather than debug the program and potentially its dependencies, for my purposes, it would be fine if it would just crash silently without making the dialog box (I have another component that is meant to restart it). Is this possible to do via some sort of manifest or Windows API call?

Comment: There's a Windows setting that hides that dialog box. Off the top of my head I can't remember it, but googling should help.

Comment: For example [this](https://monitormyweb.com/guides/how-to-disable-stopped-working-message-in-windows), untested by me, no recommendation implied.

Comment: You should take care you don't create a crash -> restart -> crash loop that slows down the computer. Perhaps limit the number of restarts in a given time interval.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a Windows API function called `SetErrorMode`. Passing the parameter `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX` will prevent the error dialog from being displayed on a crash.

There is also the `RegisterApplicationRestart` function which can be used to have Windows restart an application in the event of a crash (or other configurable reasons).